# Sabre Refresh Session - OTA_PingRQ response says Invalid version

Tags: sabre

Attempting to refresh a session, but getting Error Invalid version. I know the session is good because I can take the same BinarySecurityToken and close the session.

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <From>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Foo</PartyId>
         </From>
         <To>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Sabre webservices.havail.sabre.com</PartyId>
         </To>
         <CPAId>***</CPAId>
         <ConversationId>1564099200</ConversationId>
         <Service type="sabreXML">OTA_PingRQ</Service>
         <Action>OTA_PingRQ</Action>
         <MessageData>
            <MessageId>1564099200</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2019-07-26T00:00:000</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2019-07-26T00:00:000</TimeToLive>
         </MessageData>
      </MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESC!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-2991842063860894070!1557562!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <OTA_PingRQ TimeStamp="2019-07-26T16:36:58-6:00" Version="1.0.0">
         <EchoData>refreshed</EchoData>
      </OTA_PingRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have attempted changing the version number, but no dice.

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" mustUnderstand="1">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Sabre webservices.havail.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Foo</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>****</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>1564099200</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML">Session</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>OTA_PingRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>8222820814369030622</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2019-07-26T22:37:16</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1564099200</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESC!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-2991842063860894070!1557562!0</BinarySecurityToken>
      </Security>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <OTA_PingRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" Version="1.0.0">
         <Errors>
            <Error Type="VER">Invalid version</Error>
         </Errors>
      </OTA_PingRS>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think it refers to the version on the `header`, try adding version to the `"MessageHeader" Element`:

```
MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" version="1.0"
```

Comment: My sample already has that message header, are you referring to something else?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
....
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

or

```
<OTA_PingRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" TimeStamp="2020-03-17T04:14:00+08:00" Version="1.0.0">
    <EchoData>refreshed</EchoData>
</OTA_PingRQ>
```